# iOS Parse RSS Into TableView By Alphabetical Order

Tags: ios, uitableview, xml-parsing, rss

I am parsing an XML file that just contains title, description, and link for each item in the XML.  I have done sorting before using the pubDate section, but on this, I would just like it to be either in alphabetical order, or in the order listed in the XML. Suggestions on doing this?  On past versions I have sorted it like this:

```
for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {

                    int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                        RSSEntry *entry1 = (RSSEntry *) a;
                        RSSEntry *entry2 = (RSSEntry *) b;
                        return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
                    }];

                    [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following in viewDidLoad(),Which is for sorting Array data by ascending order..

```
        artistArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dic setObject:@"ravi" forKey:@"artist"];
        [artistArray addObject:dic];
        [dic release];

        dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dic setObject:@"srinu" forKey:@"artist"];
        [artistArray addObject:dic];
        [dic release];

        dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dic setObject:@"bobby" forKey:@"artist"];
        [artistArray addObject:dic];
        [dic release];
        dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dic setObject:@"xyz" forKey:@"artist"];
        [artistArray addObject:dic];
        [dic release];

        NSLog(@"before sorting--%@",artistArray);


        NSSortDescriptor *sortByName=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"artist" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
         NSArray *sortedArray=[artistArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        NSLog(@"After sorting---%@",sortedArray);
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses my situation at all